How to use MEGA.nz for a flutter project?
I'm quite new at coding and I'm using Flutter for an iOS app. The idea is to login to MEGA.nz, grab folders with videos on it with my account and use a video player library that supports .avi format videos. However, while researching online I have found that this is the api:
https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs but it's not quite working
my code so far:
TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();


void login(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        'a': 'us',
        'user': email,
        'password': password
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('Login successfully: $data');
    }else if(response.statusCode == 301
      print('Redirected to: ${response.headers['Location']}');
    } else {
      print('Failed login: ${response.statusCode} ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}

I keep getting logged in successfully with my credentials, even when they are wrong

"it's not quite working" is hard to help with. Is there any error message?

So this app is just for you? or are you intending to share your mega.nz creds with all the users?

Hi all, sorry lol, fair enough, it says “login successful” but even with wrong credentials, no matter what I type in

The app will be used for everyone to log in with their Mega.nz account, the idea of the app is to log in to a page which will authenticate their credentials and will be validated by the Mega api in the backend
